# php string related to html text box

Tags: php, html

i have a string variable in php where it should fit inside different textbox. is it possible?
as an example

```
<?php
  print "UserName Balance 100";
?>
```

and html form

```
<html>
<head><title>test Page</title></head>
<body>
<form method="" action="">
username : <input type="text" value="$php value in here" disabled><br>
Balance : <input type="text" value="$php value in here" disabled><br>
Amount : <input type="text" value="$php value in here" disabled> 
</form>
```

as u can see i want to put that string variable into these 3 box The "UserName" goes in first box then "Balance" in second box and then the third one.

just dont know how to do that. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're asking?

```
$data ='UserName Balance 100';

$result = explode(" ", $data);
?>
<body>
<form method="" action="">
username : <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result[0]; ?>" disabled><br>
Balance : <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result[1]; ?>" disabled><br>
Amount : <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result[2]; ?>" disabled> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thank u very much, i lova ya man. it's working :P
thx to u all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
echo "username : <input type=\"text\" value=\"$username\" disabled><br>";
echo "Balance : <input type=\"text\" value="\$balance\" disabled><br>";
echo "Amount : <input type=\"text\" value="\$amount\" disabled>";
```

Comment: it's not like that.

the print "some string text"; this is just a string and i want to put it into three different box using any split.

Comment: $content = "some text here";

in html form i want those 3 word in three box

Comment: If the strings are constant, you don't need PHP at all.  Otherwise, see SpencerX's answer... and if SpencerX's answer helps you, don't forget to accept it as correct.